# need explanation for wordpress plugin error message

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to make a plugin work on my site. can someone explain clearly what this error message means?:

> **Warning:** fopen(http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/zoomsearch/zoomsearch.css): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/me/example.com/wp-content/plugins/zoomsearch_wpplugin/zoomsearch.php on line 197

Comment: It is what it says it is...there is no file named `zoomsearch.css` in the path `/wp-content/plugins/zoomsearch/zoomsearch.css`. Look up what `fopen()` does on Google, open `/wp-content/plugins/zoomsearch_wpplugin/zoomsearch.php` and look on  on `line 197` and see why it's trying to `fopen()`.

Comment: it was looking for the css file in a folder called zoomsearch in the plugins folder. well, that folder is actually called zoomsearch_wpplugin. so, i fixed that on line 197 and the error message is gone.    thanks